# CSS general element takes precedence over classes?

Tags: html, css, inheritance

```css
ul {
  width: 250px;
}
li {
  margin: 10px;
}
ul.illuminations {
  list-style-position: outside;
}
ul.season {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
ul.2 {
  list-style: inside circle;
  width: 300px;
}
li.3 {
  margin: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="illuminations">
  <li>That idol, black eyes and yellow mop, without parentsw our court ...</li>
  <li>Gracious son of Pan! Around your forehead crowned with flowerets ...</li>
  <li>When the world is reduced to a single dark wood for our four...</li>
</ul>
<hr />
<ul class="season">
  <li>Once, if my memory serves me well, my life was a banquet...</li>
  <li>Hadn't I once a youth that was lovely, heroic, and fabulous...</li>
  <li>Autumn already! - But why regret the everlasting sun if we are</li>
</ul>
<hr />
<h1>Quotes from Edgar Allan Poe</h1>
<ul class="2">
  <li class="3">I have great faith in fools; self-confidence my friends call it.</li>
  <li class="3">All that we see or seem is but a dream within a dream.</li>
  <li class="3">I would define, in brief, the poetry of words as the rhythmical creation of beauty.</li>
</ul>
```

The first two lists do acquire the different marker positions. However, the last list doesn't acquire the list style and width attributes that I intend it to by using the more specific declarations. This is a problem I've encountered many times now. Why is this and how am I supposed to target specific elements in order to override attributes?

Comment: Class names cannot begin with number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS identifiers can't begin with a digit. So `.2` and `.3` are invalid selectors. You can escape them as `.\32` and `.\33`.

```css
ul {
  width: 250px;
}
li {
  margin: 10px;
}
ul.\32 {
  list-style: inside circle;
  width: 300px;
}
li.\33 {
  margin: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="2">
  <li class="3">I have great faith in fools; self-confidence my friends call it.</li>
  <li class="3">All that we see or seem is but a dream within a dream.</li>
  <li class="3">I would define, in brief, the poetry of words as the rhythmical creation of beauty.</li>
</ul>
```